# How do you unstack columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, 'df' and have 53 different columns and 1740 rows. The columns include; 'Age', 'RaceOne', 'RaceTwo', 'RaceThree', 'Name', 'Identity' .. etc. But I want to reorganize the DataFrame so that a new variable 'RaceTimes' replaces 'RaceOne', 'RaceTwo', 'RaceThree' and the remainder of the DataFrame columns follows suit in a particular manner, as shown in the second DataFrame below...

Current df:

```
'Age'   'RaceOne'   'RaceTwo'   'RaceThree'   'Name'   'Identity'   ...   'Male/Female         
 25      15:40:00    15:35:00    15:39:00      Wendy     105888     ...    Female
 26      15:43:00    15:25:00    15:15:00      Steve     114342     ...    Male
 22      15:20:00    15:31:00    15:23:00      Ant       123553     ...    Male
```

What I'd like to see...

```
'Age'   'RaceTimes'   'Name'   'Identity'   ...   'Male/Female'
 25      15:40:00      Wendy    105888      ...    Female
 25      15:35:00      Wendy    105888      ...    Female
 25      15:39:00      Wendy    105888      ...    Female
 26      15:43:00      Steve    114342      ...    Male
 26      15:25:00      Steve    114342      ...    Male
 26      15:15:00      Steve    114342      ...    Male
 22      15:20:00      Ant      123553      ...    Male
 22      15:31:00      Ant      123553      ...    Male
 22      15:23:00      Ant      123553      ...    Male
```

Comment: why do you have `Race` values for age 22 populated for age 26? did i miss something?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! *Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, check [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
final=(pd.wide_to_long(df,'Race',i='Age',j='v',sep='',suffix='\w+').reset_index(1,drop=True)
 .sort_index().reset_index())
```

---

```
   Age Male/Female   Name  Identity  ...      Race
0   22        Male    Ant    123553  ...  15:20:00
1   22        Male    Ant    123553  ...  15:31:00
2   22        Male    Ant    123553  ...  15:23:00
3   25      Female  Wendy    105888  ...  15:40:00
4   25      Female  Wendy    105888  ...  15:35:00
5   25      Female  Wendy    105888  ...  15:39:00
6   26        Male  Steve    114342  ...  15:43:00
7   26        Male  Steve    114342  ...  15:25:00
8   26        Male  Steve    114342  ...  15:15:00
```

Comment: Can I ask, how does it know to reformat 'Race One', 'Race Two', into RaceTime?

Comment: @Sam you mean rename `Race` in the final output to `RaceTime` ?

Comment: In the current df you have ‘RaceOne’, ‘RaceTwo’ etc, where does the code transform these into ‘RaceTime’ as shown in your output?

Comment: @Sam all the columns having the name which starts with `Race` are converted with suffix `\w+` meaning anything with `Raceabc..` , `Racedef`.. etc.. are converted into 1 column `Race` , check the docs for `wide_to_long` and you will see I have defined the `stubnames` parameter as `Race` , as per docs  "`*The stub name(s). The wide format variables are assumed to start with the stub names*`"

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense. Thanks, Really helpful. if you wanted to do multiple columns I could add them next to ‘Race’ assuming this suffix holds for all columns.

Comment: @Sam yes, you can pass a list of `stubnames` :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please research thoroughly.

Pandas has solution to your problem built in. 
You can convert your DataFrame from wide format to long format using **[pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)**.
**Take a look at the examples**. It's pretty straight forward.